# Determine Scala-object's class in Java

Tags: java, scala

I want to check if the given `object` (which may be created in `Scala`) is `instance-of` a specific Class (which is a `class` or an `abstract class` in `Scala`) in `Java`:

```
public boolean accept(Object object) {
    System.out.println("1: " + object);
    System.out.println("2: " + object.getClass());
    System.out.println("3: " + (object.getClass().getName() + " - " + RepointableActorRef.class.getName()));
    System.out.println("4: " + (object.getClass() == RepointableActorRef.class));
    System.out.println("5: " + (object instanceof RepointableActorRef));
    System.out.println("6: " + (object instanceof ActorRef));
    System.out.println("7: " + ActorRef.class.isAssignableFrom(RepointableActorRef.class));
    System.out.println("8: " + ActorRef.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass()));

    return object instanceof ActorRef; // Always returns false
}
```

In the above code:

`ActorRef` is a `Scala abstract class`:

```
abstract class ActorRef extends java.lang.Comparable[ActorRef] with Serializable
```

`RepointableActorRef` is a `Scala class`:

```
private[akka] class RepointableActorRef extends ActorRef
```

And `ActorRef` is super-class of `RepointableActorRef`.

When an instance of `RepointableActorRef` which is provided by `Scala` code (I can't modify it), passed to `accept` method, the following output will be printed:

```
1: class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
2: class java.lang.Class
3: java.lang.Class - akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
4: false
5: false
6: false
7: true
8: false
```

So how can i determine a Scala-object's class in Java? Or using `instance of` correctly (`object instanceof ActorRef` in the above code)?

Comment: What do you get if you print the value of `object.getClass()`?

Comment: @Tim:  `class java.lang.Class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When an instance of RepointableActorRef which is provided by Scala code (I can't modify it), passed to accept method, the following output will be printed:

No, it won't. This output means Scala code didn't return an instance of `RepointableActorRef`, it returned an instance of `Class`, and in particular it returned `RepointableActorRef.class`.

If you want to check whether this instance represents the `RepointableActorRef` class, you should compare

```
RepointableActorRef.class.equals(object)
```

If you want to check whether it represents a subtype of `ActorRef`, it should be

```
ActorRef.class.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) object)
```

(probably after a check that you got a `Class`).